# App crashes when instantiating HelpStackSDK

Tags: android

We tried integrating HelpStack by following steps given on GitHub, but we kept getting the following errors:

```
04-03 13:54:22.054 4638-4638/com.playerline.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.playerline.android/com.tenmiles.helpstack.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tenmiles.helpstack.activities.HSActivityParent.onCreate(HSActivityParent.java:48)
at com.tenmiles.helpstack.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:46)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the App Theme, which in our case is is `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

Comment: what do you have at line 48 in HSActivityParent ?

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil That is inside HelpStack SDK.